# How can I index a field using two different analyzers in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Say that I have a field "productTitle" which I want to use for my users to search for products.

I also want to apply autocomplete functionality. So I m using an autocomplete_analyzer with the following filter:

```
   "autocomplete_filter": {
        "type":     "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 2,
        "max_gram": 10
    }
```

However, at the same time when users make a search I don't want the "edge_ngram" to be applied, since it produces lot of irrelevant results.

For example when users want to search for "mi" and start typing "m", "mi".. they should get the results starting with m,mi as auto-complete options. However, when they actually make the query, they should only get results with the word "mi". Currently they also see results with "mini" etc..

Therefore, is it possible to have "productTitle" indexed using two different analyzers? Is multi-field type an option for me?

EDIT: Mapping for productTitle

```
 "productTitle" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index_analyzer" : "second",
                "search_analyzer" : "standard",
                "fields" : {
                  "raw" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              }
```

,
"second" analyzer

```
"analyzer": {
        "second": {
            "type":      "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter":   [
                "lowercase",
                "trim",
                "autocomplete_filter"
            ]
        }
```

So when I'm querying for :

```
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : {
      "match" : {
        "productTitle" : {
          "query" : "mi",
          "type" : "boolean",
          "minimum_should_match" : "2<75%"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I also get results like `"mini"`. But I need to only get results including just `"mi"`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm ... as far as I know, there is no way to apply multiple analyzers for same field ... what You can make is to use "Multi Fields".
here is an example how to apply different analyzers for "subfields":
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers

Comment: Thnx barat, that s would be my guess as well.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of preventing what you describe in your answer is to specify both `analyzer` and `search_analyzer` in your field mapping, like this:

```
"productTitle": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer": "standard"
}
```

The autocomplete `analyzer` will kick in at indexing time and tokenize your title according to your `edge_ngram` configuration and the `standard` analyzer will kick in at search time **without** applying the `edge_ngram` stuff.

In this context, there is no need for multi-fields unless you need to tokenize the `productTitle` field in different ways.

Comment: Hi Val, actually that s what I m already doing. I m using the edge_gram for indexing and then the standard analyzer for searching. But still when I search for a keyphrase, I still see the effect of the edge_gram

Comment: That's not normal. Which version of ES are you using? Also can you show the query you're sending?

Comment: I m using v1.7. I added the query in my question

Comment: You get `mini` because `mini` has been indexed with the tokens `mi`, `min` and `mini` and hence your query for `mi` matches the token `mi`, hence why you're getting the `mini` document. That's perfectly normal. That's  exactly the job of the `edge_ngram` token filter.

Comment: I understand that Val, that s why barat proposed that I use mutli-fields to index data using two analyzers. Once to be used for auto-complete and the other one for search. In that case when the user types "m", "mi" they will get  "mini" as an auto-complete option, but when they make the query, they will only get results with "mi" exlcluding the "mini". This it what i

Comment: Ok, I understand, that wasn't 100% clear what behavior you were expecting. Fair enough.

Comment: You may be right. Apologies for the misunderstanding. i ll edit the question to be more clear to the readers.